# Insert to all columns instead of specify each one [MYSQL or PSQL]

Tags: php, postgresql, psql

i fight with specific problem i need to insert data to multiple tables with different structure.

Atm I have my script like this:

```
  public function insertToPsql($manufacturer_code, $main_type, $subtype_code, $manufacturer, $model, $submodel)
    {
        try {
            $con = new PDO( PSQL_DB_HOST, PSQL_DB_HOST, PSQL_DB_HOST );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO car_type(manufacturer_code, main_type, subtype_code, manufacturer, model, submodel) VALUES(:manufacturer_code, :main_type, :subtype_code, :manufacturer, :model, :submodel)";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'manufacturer_code', $manufacturer_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'main_type', $main_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'subtype_code', $subtype_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'manufacturer', $manufacturer, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'model', $model, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'submodel', $submodel, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

The thing is this is not the best idea if I need to edit it always for each  table ( many of my tables have around 40 columns ).

Good thing is that I always insert all of them. Is there some way how to  insert to all columns and dont specify data but just give it an array or object of all data?

Something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO car_type VALUES(:$data)";
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? You have both tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array whose elements are in the same order as the columns in the table, you can do:

```
$values = array($manufacturer_code, $main_type, $subtype_code, $manufacturer, $model, $submodel);
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO car_type VALUES ($placeholders)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
```